# Setting a vim option from the command line?

Tags: invocation, options

How does one set a vim option when launching from bash or another shell?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```bash
$ vim -c 'set ai'
```

See `:h -c`, `:h startup` and `$ vim --help`.

Comment: If you intend to open multiple windows (`vim -O` or `vim -o`) and want to set this command for all of them, use `-c windo <option>`. Example: `vim -O -c 'windo set ai'`).

Comment: Example I would find useful: `vim -c 'set wrap' /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: If you want to set multiple options, separate them with the pipe character, like `vim -c 'set ai | set nowrap'`

Comment: Does `set ai nowrap` not work for you @wisbucky? You should be able to set multiple options with a single `set` command.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Thanks, I didn't know about that! (Well, I guess my comment can still be helpful if you need to run different commands)

Comment: wish this worked with gvim in addition, but no luck :(

Comment: @philwalk, this works with GVim too when launched from your shell.

Comment: @ romainl thanks for checking, but it apparently only works when gvim is compiled with the right options.  The gvim.exe for Windows on my system tries to edit command line options as if they are filenames

Comment: @philwalk it works for gvim with **double** quotes. Example: `gvim -c "set ic list" filename.txt` (tested with gvim 8.2 in cmd.exe on Win7)